# After the server restarts, the network card fails. How can I solve it?

Tags: networking

As the question is, I use the Google Cloud VM, and the following error occurs after restarting, and the external network cannot be connected. How can I solve this problem?

```
Aug 12 23:30:01 server systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Aug 12 23:30:01 server systemd: Started Session 37 of user root.
Aug 12 23:30:01 server systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8395] policy: auto-activating connection 'System eth0' (fa741868-5fc1-4287-9356-c3204a797853)
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8402] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'System eth0' (fa741868-5fc1-4287-9356-c3204a797853)
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8403] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8406] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8407] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8412] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8414] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8465] dhcp4 (eth0): dhclient started with pid 2429
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8475] dhcp4 (eth0): client pid 2429 exited with status 127
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8475] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 12 23:33:40 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782420.8476] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8063] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8066] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <warn>  [1628782452.8069] device (eth0): Activation: failed for connection 'System eth0'
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8071] device (eth0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8083] policy: auto-activating connection 'System eth0' (fa741868-5fc1-4287-9356-c3204a797853)
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8088] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'System eth0' (fa741868-5fc1-4287-9356-c3204a797853)
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8089] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8091] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8093] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8096] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8098] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8161] dhcp4 (eth0): dhclient started with pid 2430
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8171] dhcp4 (eth0): client pid 2430 exited with status 127
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8171] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 12 23:34:12 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782452.8172] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8174] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8179] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <warn>  [1628782483.8182] device (eth0): Activation: failed for connection 'System eth0'
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8184] device (eth0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8196] policy: auto-activating connection 'System eth0' (fa741868-5fc1-4287-9356-c3204a797853)
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8200] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'System eth0' (fa741868-5fc1-4287-9356-c3204a797853)
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8201] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8204] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8205] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8208] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8210] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8274] dhcp4 (eth0): dhclient started with pid 2431
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8284] dhcp4 (eth0): client pid 2431 exited with status 127
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8284] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 12 23:34:43 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782483.8285] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8128] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8132] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <warn>  [1628782515.8135] device (eth0): Activation: failed for connection 'System eth0'
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8137] device (eth0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8150] policy: auto-activating connection 'System eth0' (fa741868-5fc1-4287-9356-c3204a797853)
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8154] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'System eth0' (fa741868-5fc1-4287-9356-c3204a797853)
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8155] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8157] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8159] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8162] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8164] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8231] dhcp4 (eth0): dhclient started with pid 2432
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8241] dhcp4 (eth0): client pid 2432 exited with status 127
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8241] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed unknown -> done
Aug 12 23:35:15 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782515.8243] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 12 23:35:46 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782546.8080] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 23:35:46 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782546.8084] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 12 23:35:46 server NetworkManager[425]: <warn>  [1628782546.8087] device (eth0): Activation: failed for connection 'System eth0'
Aug 12 23:35:46 server NetworkManager[425]: <info>  [1628782546.8089] device (eth0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Comment: Server should not use  dhcp? Sofar disable it and set it static

Comment: How do I do it? Can you give me some pointers? Or provide a method of operation? ! Grateful!

Comment: You should know how basic networking will do on your Distribution. Else only Superuser.com is the right way to ask